# Show single bar graph and a stacked bar graph in the same plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file like this:

```
"Execution"  500
"Overhead 1" 200
"Overhead 2" 75
```

I am trying to plot a histogram of this data that shows the *Execution* time as a single bar graph but *Overhead 1* and *Overhead 2* as a single stacked bar graph.

This is what I have so far:

```
set terminal postscript eps 24
set output "wq_time_profile.eps"
set size 0.95,0.95
set boxwidth 1.0 relative    
set style fill solid 0.5 noborder   
set style data histogram 
set style histogram cluster gap 1  
set ylabel "Time (mins)"                                                                      
plot "wq_time_profile.dat" u 1 notitle, "" u 2 notitle, "" u 3 notitle
```

I can't quite get my head around how to show rows 2 and 3 as a stacked bar graph while showing row 1 as standalone bar graph in the same plot. Is this possible in gnuplot? I am using gnuplot v4.2. Thanks!

EDIT: Modified the title and question to clarify that the plot needs to contain a single standalone bar graph and a stacked bar graph in the same gat the same plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
set style fill solid 0.5 noborder
set style histogram columnstacked
set style data histogram
set ylabel "Time (mins)"
plot "test.dat" u 2 notitle with histogram
```

If you want to have a key with the colors-labels in it:

```
set style histogram columnstacked
set style data histogram
set style fill solid 0.5 noborder
set ylabel "Time (mins)"
plot "test.dat" u 2:key(1) with histogram
```

---

After reading your edit and playing around a bit, this is still possible, but I needed to modify your datafile.  (I hope that's Ok):

```
"Execution"  500


"foo" NaN
"Overhead 1" 200
"Overhead 2" 75
```

Now the plotting script:

```
set style histogram columnstacked
set style data histogram
set style fill solid 0.5 noborder
set ylabel "Time (mins)"
plot for [i=0:1] "test.dat" index i u ($2):key(1) with histogram
```

There are a bunch of subtleties here.  The pair of blank records is a way to create a separate "index" for gnuplot to use when plotting.  The first bar is by itself in a dataset.  Here's the problem, Gnuplot will match the first record from index 0 with the first record from index 1 and plot them with the same color.  That's ugly.  So we need to insert a fake record in the index=1 dataset which won't make any plot, but will take up a color.   That's what the `"foo" NaN` line is designed to do.  I also needed to modify the `plot` line to plot both of the indexes.  And the using specification needs to change from `2:key(1)` to `($2):key(1)` as there is a slight difference in how the two forms handle missing data.

Comment: Thanks mgilson for the answer! However, I realized that I wasn't quite clear in my question. I edited it now to clarify it. What I was trying to do in the question was to show row 1 in a single bar graph while showing row 2 and row 3 together in a stacked bar graph.